# jQuery inserting element .before() and .after() does not work as expected, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, insert, element

I am trying to dynamically surround sets of IMG and A tags with a div tag but am unable to make it work.

my html:

```
<img class="myClass-1" src="img5" />
<a class="myClass-2" href="url"></a>
```

my script:

```
$('img.myClass-1').each(function(){
   $(this).before('<div style="position: relative;">');
   $(this).next().after('</div>');
});
```

my Firebug outcome:

```
<div style="position: relative;"/>
<img class="myClass-1" src="img5" />
<a class="myClass-2" href="url"></a>
```

What I am trying to accomplish:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
<img class="myClass-1" src="img5" />
<a class="myClass-2" href="url"></a>
</div>
```

I replaced

```
$(this).next().after('</div>');
```

with

```
$(this).next().after('<p>test</p>');
```

just to see if it was unable to execute the .next().after() code but it works fine. I am new to using jQuery and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can somebody help? Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/), like this:

```
$(this).next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div style="position: relative;" />');
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hUGgD/), this takes `<img>` and `<a>` then wraps them *both* in that `<div>` container.

Comment: jQuery is very semantic. I am impressed that you can write code like that with it. (I'm trying to move away from prototype towards jQuery.)

Comment: WOW! This works great! Thank you so much. How do you find out that there is (and can use things like) .andSelf().wrapAll(...) ?

Comment: @Angie - The API site has all methods and what they're for :) http://api.jquery.com/ You learn by needing/finding them I suppose, that's how I go anyway :)

Comment: Thanks, I do go there a lot but am not always able to find what I'm looking for... a skill I need to improve upon :o) I never came across any mention of .andSelf() & .wrapAll() but the more I learn about what can be done with jQuery the more I love it!

Answer (score 1):

You could also get rid of the each() (or just replace this with your selector in Nick's snippet):

```
$('img.myClass-1').next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div style="position: relative;" />');
```